# How to aggregate rows into one month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm attempting to combine data that I am selecting from another table.

This table has a column named `IdClient_PK` which is a uniqueID and a column `DateJoinKey` which is the date this user viewed a page.

I would like to combine all `DateJoinKey` into one month. So For example:

| IDClient_PK | DateJoinKey | Views |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0E984725-C51C-4BF4-9960-E1C80E27ABA0 | 01-1-2021 | 2 |
| 0E984725-C51C-4BF4-9960-E1C80E27ABA0 | 01-3-2021 | 1 |
| 0E984725-C51C-4BF4-9960-E1C80E27ABA0 | 01-14-2021 | 3 |
| 0E984725-C51C-4BF4-9960-E1C80E27ABA0 | 01-21-2021 | 1 |

I'm attempting to get a result that looks like this:

| IDClient_PK | DateJoinKey | Views |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0E984725-C51C-4BF4-9960-E1C80E27ABA0 | 01-1-2021 | 7 |

How am I able to do this?

I attempted using the `FORMAT()` statement in SQL but I run into an error saying: `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Here is an example of my query:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpModule2(
        [IdClient_PK] uniqueidentifier,
        [DateJoinKey] DATETIME,
        [Views] INT 
)


INSERT INTO #tmpModule ([IdClient_PK],[DateJoinKey], [Views] )
SELECT          a.[IdClient_PK],
                FORMAT(a.DateJoinKey, 'yyyy-MM'),
                SUM(a.ViewValue)
FROM  [usage].[Fact_RegisteredUsers_UserReport] a
GROUP BY
a.IdClient_PK,
FORMAT(a.DateJoinKey, 'yyyy-MM'),
```

Answer (score 1):

`FORMAT()` returns a `NVARCHAR` data type, but your temp table has that column as a `DATETIME`.  You can either change your `CREATE` to use the proper data type or `SELECT INTO` like below.  Or you could convert that returned column that you have above to a `DATETIME` before you insert into your temp table.

```
SELECT          a.[IdClient_PK],
                FORMAT(a.DateJoinKey, 'yyyy-MM') as [DateJoinKey],
                SUM(a.ViewValue) AS [Views]
INTO #tmpModule
FROM  [usage].[Fact_RegisteredUsers_UserReport] a
GROUP BY
a.IdClient_PK,
FORMAT(a.DateJoinKey, 'yyyy-MM')
```